# Obtain Type of Value Stored in YAML::Node for yaml-cpp

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

Given this code:

```
void LoadFromYaml(const YAML::Node& node){
    const YAML::Node& Data=node["Data"];
    if(Data){
        if(Data.ValueIsInt)// Do something with integer.
        if(Data.ValueIsFloat)// Do something with float.
        if(Data.ValueIsString)// Do something with string.
    }
}
```

How do I check is the data contained in the YAML Node 'Data' is an integer, float, or a string? Note: I don't want to check if the Node is a scalar, map, sequence, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Throwing lots of exceptions while parsing can impact your parsing speed. Not sure why `yaml-cpp` doesn't have an `is_type<T>` method or something similar to `std::optional` or `std::expected` getters

Hacky way to get around it though with Boost - injecting your own template specialisation into the `YAML` namespace and return `std::optional` (or `boost::optional` if you don't have C++17)

// yaml-cpp/patch.hpp

```
#pragma once

#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>

#include <optional>
#include <string>

namespace YAML {

template <typename T>
struct as_if<T, std::optional<T>> {
  explicit as_if(const Node &node) :
      node(node) {
  }
  const Node &node;

  std::optional<T> operator()() const {
    std::optional<T> val;
    T decoded;
    if ((node.m_pNode != nullptr) && convert<T>::decode(node, decoded)) {
      val = std::move(decoded);
    }

    return val;
  }
};

// There is already a string partial specialisation, so we need a full specialisation here
template <>
struct as_if<std::string, std::optional<std::string>> {
  explicit as_if(const Node &node) :
      node(node) {
  }
  const Node &node;

  std::optional<std::string> operator()() const {
    std::optional<std::string> val;
    std::string decoded;
    if ((node.m_pNode != nullptr) && convert<std::string>::decode(node, decoded)) {
      val = std::move(decoded);
    }

    return val;
  }
};

} // namespace YAML
```

You can then run something like

```
std::optional<bool> as_bool          = YAML::as_if<bool, std::optional<bool> >(node)();
std::optional<int> as_int            = YAML::as_if<int, std::optional<int> >(node)();
std::optional<double> as_double      = YAML::as_if<double, std::optional<double> >(node)();
std::optional<std::string> as_string = YAML::as_if<std::string, std::optional<std::string> >(node)();
```

Total cost of construction here is 4 optional values + 4 default values. This may or may not be faster than dealing with the exceptions, I haven't tested.

Comment: Jeeze, thanks for the answer! I actually forgot that I had this question. Exceptions are pretty slow since they unroll the stack so I imagine that your solution is plenty fast.

Comment: Yeah I think so - the whole rationale of proposals like `std::expected` is to make the success and failure pathways for things like this equally weighted. But left that in so people know to do their homework. I've used this in a drop-in `.d` style YAML parser so the expectation there is that we know almost nothing in advance on what the document looks like - hence avoiding exceptions as much as I can.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to convert the node to each type:

```
try {
  int value = data.as<int>();
  // do something
} catch (const BadConversion& e) {
  // do something else
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what would be a good way to code the try/catch blocks in series for the 3 types? Or is nesting it the only way?

Comment: Yeah; you'll have to decide what behavior you want when several are true. For example, it'll always be a string (if it's a scalar), and if it's an int, it'll also be a float.

Comment: Okay, so testing for float, then int, then string should do the trick.

Comment: Using exceptions for flow control is a bad idea. It could really hurt the performance.